# Is there a way to set all values of a dictionary to zero?

Tags: python

For example, I have a list of ASCII characters and want to zip them with a list of zeroes equal to the number of characters in the ASCII list,

like:

```
    import string

    a = string.printable
    #Gives all ASCII characters as a list ^
    b = zeroes * len(a)
    c = zip(a,b)
```

Something like that?

Comment: So, you need a list of tuples, or a dict?

Answer (score 12):

You can use a dict comprehension:

```
{ x:0 for x in string.printable}
```

Comment: That's Python 3.x exclusive, it will raise Syntax Error in 2.6 at least (not sure about 2.7)

Comment: You are correct that it doesn't work in Python 2.6 but it works fine in Python 2.7. "[New in Python 2.7 are dictionary comprehensions](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/dict-comprehensions.html)"

Comment: Thank you, this is an elegant solution. My next question would be then, if I needed an if statement that tallied the existence of ASCII characters in a list, could I add 1 to each term in the ASCIIDict I created for every matching character I find?

Comment: @Austin: Have you considered Tim's answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13508872/61974

Comment: I was using `dict(zip(items, [0 for _ in items]))` in my situation.  I knew there had to be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 8):

There is a standard method for that:

```
mydict = dict.fromkeys(string.printable, 0)
```

or, if you need a list of tuples (to be quite honest, Martijn's version of that is more pythonic, but just for variety):

```
import itertools
tuples = zip(string.printable, itertools.repeat(0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a list comprehension:

```
c = [(i, 0) for i in a]
```

Comment: This is a list of tuples, not a dictionary. If I know my python right, then you'll have to cast it to a dict: `dict([(i, 0) for i in a])`

Comment: @Jack: the question was ambiguous as to what they wanted. For dictionary output just use `dict.fromkeys()` (*much* faster).

Answer (score 1):

It may not help you, but if you are going to be using the dictionary to count you can use a `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(int)
```

Any key is then set to 0 by default.

```
>>> print my_dict['a']
    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this, if you need a list:

```
import string
c = zip(string.printable, [0]*len(string.printable))
```